# Can anyone tell me how to convert the detected text from live camera to speech. So far I can detect the text but don't know to convert it into speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

**This is the code for detecting text from camera.**

I am new to the android platform. Now I am working on TTS(Text to Speech).So far I have detected text from image and I would like it to be converted to speech.
can anyone help me out?

```
  package com.example.textdemo;
  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.Manifest;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.provider.MediaStore;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
  import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
  import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
  import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText;
  import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //find imageview
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageId);
    //find textview
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textId);
    //check app level permission is granted for Camera
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        //grant the permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 101);
    }
}


public void doProcess(View view) {
    //open the camera => create an Intent object
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    //from bundle, extract the image
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
    //set image in imageview
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    //process the image
    //1. create a FirebaseVisionImage object from a Bitmap object
    FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    //2. Get an instance of FirebaseVision
    FirebaseVision firebaseVision = FirebaseVision.getInstance();
    //3. Create an instance of FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer
    FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer firebaseVisionTextRecognizer = 
    firebaseVision.getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
    //4. Create a task to process the image
    Task<FirebaseVisionText> task = 
   firebaseVisionTextRecognizer.processImage(firebaseVisionImage);
    //5. if task is success
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
            String s = firebaseVisionText.getText();
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });

    //6. if task is failure
    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is my xml code of image to text

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageId"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="take pic"
    android:onClick="doProcess"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textId"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Should I add text to speech code in this activity only?

Answer (score 1):

There is a class called TextToSpeech (TTS), which you can use to perform basic TTS, or you can do it over a network call using TTS Api's, such as Google Cloud TTS [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech)

Here is an [article](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/make-your-android-apps-talk-with-text-to-speech-99a73d62c948) that I wrote about it.

Comment: That's great, you can mark this response as a valid one.